# compute bounds in Path object returns 0

Tags: java, android, graphics

I have a simple drawing app for android and I would like to detect if a user has clicked on a line. To speed this process up I would like to get the bounds of all the Paths and check if the user input is within the bounds to quickly eliminate some of the paths.

The problem I am encountering is that the method:

```
    pathInstance.computeBounds(boundsObject,false);
```

Always returns 0, Or rather a rect containing all 0's.

Weirdly if I debug my app and while the app is stopped at a breakpoint I draw on the screen, the computeBounds works when the app continues to execute

Has anyone had this before? I can post my code but I was just wondering if it was a common problem first?

edit: I know what the problem is now and have hacked around it but This solution still doesn't work. The problem is is that when the user first inputs data eg a touch that touch is drawn to the screen and as I add points to that path it never updates the Bounds calculation. I am now manually iterating through the points and calculating the bounds myself.

code:
DrawingPanel.java:

```
for (int index = 0; index < mSketches.size(); index++) {
            Sketch s = mSketches.get(index);
            canvas.drawPath(s.getPath().getPath(), s.getPaint());
            canvas.drawRect(10,10,50,50,rad);
            RectF temp = s.computeBounds();

            for (int i = 0; i < s.mEnds.size(); i++){
                canvas.drawPoint(s.mEnds.get(i).first, s.mEnds.get(i).second , endsPaint);
                canvas.drawCircle(s.mEnds.get(i).first , s.mEnds.get(i).second , END_STICK_WIDTH, rad);
            }
            canvas.drawRect(s.computeBounds(),rad);
        }
```

Where Sketch is basicly a Pair of paint and path.

Thanks,

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to post your code.

Comment: Its hard to help without knowing all your object types, what is pathInstance? What is boundsObject? When a user touches the screen what is the code thats executed? It sounds like you found out that the bounds are not being updated but have you ensured that the points your adding to the path are in fact going to the same path your using to detect collisions? Try making a http://sscce.org/ to post on here and likely you will find your problem while you make it.

Comment: I shall try to make a small example. as for your questions that is pseudo code for pathInstance and boundsObject where path Instance is an instance of a Path object and boundsObject is a Rect as is required by computeBounds. Yes the following actions are being appended to the same path.